# Vectorising stringr::str_count

Tags: r

I'm trying to vectorise the 'pattern' argument of stringr::str_count in R as follows:

```
# Define the patterns you want to count
patterns <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")

# Create a vectorized version of str_count
vectorized_str_count <- Vectorize(str_count, vectorize.args = "pattern")

# Input string
string <- "I like apples, bananas, and oranges. Apples are my favorite."

# Count the occurrences of patterns in the string
counts <- vectorized_str_count(string, pattern = patterns)

# Print the counts
print(counts)
```

I am  expecting to get 2, 1, 1 as outputs since there are two occurences of 'apple' in the original string. However it returns 1, 1, 1

How can I amend the code to get what I'm after? I know I could do this by constructing a regex search term but there are various reasons I don't want to do this due to other problems. Many thanks

Comment: Since "apple" is not in "Apples", you might want `vectorized_str_count(tolower(string), pattern = patterns)`

Comment: Another option is to change your pattern: `patterns[1] <- "apple|Apple"`

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring - schoolboy error! Now working well thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use `str_count` directly: `pattern2 <- paste0(patterns, collapse = "|"); str_count(string, regex(pattern2, ignore_case = T))`

Comment: @LMc But that returns a completely different value.

Answer (score 1):

`str_count()` is already vectorised over the `pattern` argument.

You get only
one match for the first pattern because the pattern is case-sensitive: `apple`
does not match `Apple`. Add `(?i)` or use `regex()` to make a pattern case-insensitive:

```r
library(stringr)

x <- "I like apples, bananas, and oranges. Apples are my favorite."
str_count(x, c("(?i)apple", "banana", "orange"))
#> [1] 2 1 1
str_count(x, regex(c("apple", "banana", "orange"), ignore_case = TRUE))
#> [1] 2 1 1
```